# Can I develop Sliding Dashboard Using SSRS 2008

Tags: ssrs-2008, dashboard

I need to develop a dashboard that will be displayed in a flat screen hanging from the wall. Not on a PC (of course, behind the cabinet or something there is a PC, but I mean, without any user involvement).

But the info to display does not fit a single screen, so I need to have 4-5 screens sliding / rotating with the info.

Is that something that can be done using SSRS 2008?

If yes, how?
If not, do you have good free/low-cost suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Create the 4/5 'screens' within their own Rectangle in the one report
- Set the `AutoRefresh` property of the report to *x* number of seconds you want for the rotation to occur.
- Based on the AutoRefresh length you have set, set the visibility of the various rectangles based on a formula.

**Example**

- Set AutoRefresh to 15 seconds
- We will assume you have 4 rectangles/'slides'
- *Therefore*, each slide will be shown once every minute
- We set the visibility of each rectangle independently using an `IIf()` function and testing the current time with the `Now()` function
- **Rectangle 1**

  - `=IIf(Second(Now()) < 15, False, True)` the rectangle will show if the AutoRefresh occured during the first 15 second block of the current minute, all other times during that minute it will be hidden.
- **Rectangle 2**

  - `=IIf(Second(Now()) >= 15 AND Second(Now()) < 30, False, True)` the rectangle will show if the AutoRefresh occurred during the second 15 second block of the current minute, all other times during that minute it will be hidden.
- **Rectangle 3**

  - `=IIf(Second(Now()) >= 30 AND Second(Now()) < 45, False, True)` the rectangle will show if the AutoRefresh occurred during the third 15 second block of the current minute, all other times during that minute it will be hidden.
- **Rectangle 4**

  - `=IIf(Second(Now()) >= 45, False, True)` the rectangle will show if the AutoRefresh occurred during the fourth 15 second block of the current minute, all other times during that minute it will be hidden.

Other combinations can be done for the `IIf()` looking at the current `Minute()` or current `Hour()`. The `Mod()` function could also be used to show things every say 5 minutes as well.

Comment: Hey, if this works, you are a genius. I'll give it a try. It will take me some time, though, so you may not hear back from me today. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but I was more than 8 days without power in New York! I'm catching up and will get to this next week. Thanks.

Comment: I commented here before that "if this works, you are a genius". Well, you are! This is absolutely beautiful! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this in SSRS 2008 on it's own. However you could simply render you report pages as images and then use a free slideshow tool (picasa is good but there are lots available) to play a slide show of the images.

Alternatively you could put together a webpage to rotate the images but I'm taking the easiest, least technical route here.

If the data needs to be 'live' then you could create a subscription to run the report(s) every xx number of minutes or whatever you need. Set the output type to TIFF and use a windows file share as the delivery method. You can also get it to overwrite existing files, so you'll end up having 4 or 5 images being overwritten every xx number of minutes.

Of course there are much more elegant ways of doing this but if you want to use SSRS and want it cheap and cheerful then this is at least an option.

Good luck!
Al.